# MySQL multiple where

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use multiple WHERE ? = ? AND ? = ? AND ? = AND but I can't get it to work. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
$randuser = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM `brukere` WHERE `level`='1' AND `liv`>='0' AND NOT `brukernavn`='$spiller->brukernavn' `liv`>='0' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

I don't know how I am going to do this. Also I don't know if `AND NOT` will work, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

- You have a condition without `AND`, since its a duplicate you may remove it (`liv>='0'`) before `ORDER BY`
- `AND NOT` will also work by I suggest you use `!=` for negation

So your query should look like

```
$randuser = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM `brukere` WHERE `level`='1' AND `liv`>='0' AND `brukernavn`!='$spiller->brukernavn' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```